# double click does not work for a changing web element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.
I need to double click on a  web element so I use:

```
action.doubleClick(webelement).build().perform();
```

but the problem is that while double-clicking the element changes, in other words, when you click on the element, it becomes highlighted, so when you double click, it gets highlighted and unhighlighted causing me to the `stale web element error`.

My solution was:

```
action.moveToElement(webelement).doubleClick().click().build().perform();
```

is this fine or are there any better way to handle this issue?

Comment: Can you show me where is the error `stale web element error` from? Your code is working fine on my machine.

Comment: Could you please post the html here and how are you locating your web element.

Answer (score 0):

@LoveJavaTwo U can try POM approach and because of POM object stale problem resolved. So try this approach or use method in same class if you don't wanna use POM.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Because on my machine with POM approche this code works fine.